# Automatic spacing with iomanip

Tags: c++, iomanip, setw

For the following code:

```
cout << left << setw(20) << "Example Header\n";
cout << setw(60) << setfill('-') << "-" << endl;
```

The second line (with the dashes) is indented by 5 spaces for some reason. I initially thought that something was automatically getting tabbed, but I can find no reason for why it would to that. No matter what goes on the second line, six spaces are automatically put in that I cannot remove. Even though a simple work around would be for me to just fill the second line with spaces, I am still curious to know why my program is putting these spaces in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cout << left << setw(20) << "Name" << setw(20) << "Number" << setw(20) << "Points Scored" 
     << endl;
  // ^^^^^^^^
```

instead of using `'\n'` fixes that.

See the [Live Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f1f1c776543a4db7).

Comment: Thanks, it works. This crossed my mind briefly, but the answers I found said the only difference between '\n' and endl was that endl cleared the output buffer. Why does this work?

Comment: @JesperJuhl I'm still [investigating about that](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/efd69a553d1eaba6). If you have a good one feel free to chime in.

Comment: Perhaps the fact that "Points Scored\n" is exactly 14=20-6 characters long should ring a bell.